# Sharepoint hardware migration

Tags: sharepoint, migration

I am currently creating a Sharepoint system for a company. I built the site on a VM server for testing and now they want to move it to a server with more HDD capacity.

The issue is that this move is 2-3 months from now and the Sharepoint site might get large and they would like to be able to migrate everything over to the new server. I know how to migrate the database, but I don't know if that is the only thing that needs to be exported/imported.

Is there anything else I should be carrying over? The software is not going to change. We are going to be using the same edition of Sharepoint and SQL server.

Thanks

Comment: Is your Sharepoint system based on a single Sharepoint/database server, or do you have a database server and a Sharepoint Web Front end?

Comment: single Sharepoint/database server... if this answer helps at all

Comment: I would strongly recommend moving to have the database and the Sharepoint WFE on separate machines if you are concerned about scaling in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your data will be stored in a database, so you could do this simply by moving the data to a physical database server with more hard disk space.  You could then keep your Web Front End(s) as virtual, or set up new Web Front Ends on physical hardware.  Some of this will depend on your licensing.

The procedure for moving your data is detailed by Microsoft at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725%28office.12%29.aspx for Sharepoint 2007.  I imagine they have a similar document for Sharepoint 2010, or the procedure is the same.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I'll make a few backups and take a wack at it.